# Rotating HTML Canvas Image Against EXIF Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, exif

So I am made an image upload form that takes an image and adds an overlay. The issue is that if an image is uploaded via an iPhone or Android phone, the image is usually incorrectly rotated because of the EXIF data. I have found a way to map the orientation to a number (1-10), but the code I found online to rotate the canvas doesn't seem to be working. Any help would be appreciated.

> JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Hybridx24/Loycdyc9/2/

**JS**

```
function showimagepreview(input, ori) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var filerdr = new FileReader();

    filerdr.onload = function(e) {
      var img = new Image();

      img.onload = function() {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
            ratio = img.height / img.width,
            maxRatio = 0.6666666666666667;


        var width = img.width,
            height = img.height;
        // transform context before drawing image
        switch (ori) {
          case 2: ctx.transform(-1, 0, 0, 1, width, 0); break;
          case 3: ctx.transform(-1, 0, 0, -1, width, height ); break;
          case 4: ctx.transform(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, height ); break;
          case 5: ctx.transform(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0); break;
          case 6: ctx.transform(0, 1, -1, 0, height , 0); break;
          case 7: ctx.transform(0, -1, -1, 0, height , width); break;
          case 8: ctx.transform(0, -1, 1, 0, 0, width); break;
          default: ctx.transform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
        }

        canvas.width = 640;
        canvas.height = 640;
        drawImageProp(ctx, img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);  // Centers BG image (similar to background-position: cover)

        var img2 = new Image();

        img2.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(img2, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png'),
                preview = document.getElementById('img-preview'),
                $img = $('<img id="new-img" src="' + data + '" />'),
                $downloadImg = $('#download-img'),
                $shareImg = $('#share-img');

            $img.css({'border-radius': '6px'})
            preview.innerHTML = '';
            $img.hide().appendTo(preview).fadeIn(500);
            $downloadImg.hide().appendTo(preview).fadeIn(500);
            $shareImg.hide().appendTo(preview).fadeIn(500);

            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "http://data-uri-to-img-url.herokuapp.com/images.json",
              data: { 
                 "image[data_uri]": data.split(',')[1]  // ".split(',')[1]" Safely removes Base64 prefix for POST
              }
            }).done(function(response) {
              var url = response['url'],
                  fbUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + url;

              $shareImg.find('a').attr('href', fbUrl);
              console.log(url);
            });
        };
        img2.src = "http://i.imgur.com/xNpwbZj.png"
      }
      img.src = e.target.result;
    }
    filerdr.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to rotate your canvas is to use css `transform` which takes the degrees to rotate like this:

```
document.querySelector('canvas').style.transform = 'rotate(90deg)';
```

That way you are selecting the canvas and rotating it vertically. Now you should be able to rotate your canvas based on the number that you got there. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: That only superficially changes the image - I need it to use the `ctx.transform()` so that I could have the generated image saved/shared

Comment: Have you tried the `ctx.setTransform()` method instead of the `ctx.transform()` ? I'll keep trying